# Print Record Number with a prefix

Tags: bash, shell, awk, ksh

I have a shell script that creates a CSV output file like below (on separate lines) :

```
aaa,111
bbb,222
ccc,999
```

I want to have a record number as the first column in the above output such as,

```
dm1,aaa,111
dm2,bbb,222
dm3,ccc,999
```

How do I create a variable for `dm` within my shell script?

Comment: Is it possible to have more details? How is your csv file generated? is there a loop where it's possible to add the record number?

Comment: Hello, I became a member a few hours ago so please pardon my ignorance. I am not sure why my post is off-topic since it concerns a ksh script that i was writing. In fact I got a great response within a few minutes and I able to complete the task. I have added "awk" as a tag if that was the issue. I hope it can be removed from hold soon. Or please let me know what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk`:

```
awk '{print "dm" NR "," $0}' input.csv >output.csv
```

or

```
... | awk '{print "dm" NR "," $0}' >output.csv
```

Comment: That worked like an absolute charm :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a var and expr to do some maths like

```
dm=`expr $dm + 1`
echo "dm$dm,...rest of output..."
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipe your output to `awk`

```
yourcommand | awk -F, -v prefix="dm" '{printf "%s%d,%s\n", prefix, NR, $0}'
```

we set `-F,` to set the input field separator, and the `-v` to set a prefix. You can replace "dm" with a shell variable, if you want.

Comment: Why do you split with comma? Fields are not used and I guess it would slow down the command.

Comment: Yea, you are right. Since we print the entire line, it is not necessary to split input lines in fields. Ansgar's answer should be sufficient in this case

Comment: Got a syntax error here !

Comment: @Girish what is the error message? I tested here with your sample data and I get no errors...

Comment: cat device_scr.txt | awk -F","  -v prefix="dm" '{printf "%s%d,%s\n", prefix, NR, $0}'
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: Maybe it's my awk or ksh basics that is wrong here but I have seen that any time I use a complex awk script, it bails out. I am using Solaris 10 with ksh.

Comment: @Girish It could be... My awk version is `mawk 1.3.3`. But since the other answer worked there is not point in debugging it further I guess

Comment: I will look into the awk version. It is always good to have mutiple approaches to a single problem. may have an application somewhere else. Thanks for looking into this !

Comment: Thsi worked too after using a different version of awk ! Thank you.